# Lock window size using Python's Win32 modules (win32gui, win32api, win32ui, ...)

Tags: python, winapi, window, pywin32, win32gui

I have an *external* application that is running and I obtained the application window's `HWND` (for sake of simplicity let's say it's `hwnd = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()`.

I am aware that I can resize and move the said window using `win32gui.MoveWindow(...)`.

**My question is:** am I able to set the window somehow so that the user cannot resize the window, thus locking the window size, and making the window size static?

**Bonus question:** am I also able to "lock" the window position, preventing the user from moving the window position?

Some example lines of Python code would be appreciated.

---

#### Additional Clarification Notes

- Python version: Python `3.X.X`
- Operating System: `Windows 10`
- User is Administrator: `Yes`
- Is it your own application you are trying to lock the size: `No.` *It's an external 3rd party application.*

Comment: Assuming that you didn't write the application, the only way I could think of would be to [subclass the window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/subclassing-overview) and have it intercept the [`WM_GETMINMAXINFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-getminmaxinfo) message. Entirely non-trivial.

Comment: No. I did not write the application. It's an external application.

Comment: Is your user admin on the *OS* (es) you want this to happen?

Comment: Yes, the user has administrator privileges.

Comment: @cri What opportunities would that open up as opposed to just running as a non-admin user?

Comment: @IInspectable: I reckon there are more chances for an admin to be able to interact with a foreign window (from a different process).

Comment: @cri Why would that be the case? If you're interacting with processes that run under the same user account (regardless of whether they are admin or non-admin users) they can do whatever. If you run Notepad, you can just walk in, and steal all the information you want from the same user account. That's Windows Access Control 101, really.

Comment: That's true. I was aiming to the more generic case of any user. But nevermind, I don't want to start a polemic, maybe I asked a stupid question.